# Stream video from PC camera to the internet

Tags: audio, video, streaming, video-streaming

I want to stream securely (with password) video and sound 
from my computer to several clients (browser and/or phone apps).

What are my options?

Currently I am doing this with [Dropcam](https://www.dropcam.com/) from one room. In the other room I have a computer in idle and I don't want to spend another 150$ for a second Dropcam.

**Q1:** Is it possible to use the camera & microphone from my computer and live stream them?
**Q2:** Is there a free stream tool?
**Q3:** Is it protected (private)?

Comment: This might be naïve but doesn't Skype do that out of the box?

Comment: Phone Apps maybe, didn't know Skype would stream to browser app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a straight answer as I'm not aware of any "streaming" tool, but I have a proposed alternative solution to what you wanted to do:

Use "Internet Meeting" software.

One that I'm familiar with is TeamViewer. The basic of TeamViewer is to do remote support but they have "Meeting" feature as well.

You can Host a meeting, and then let all of your clients (either using their browser - flash based, or Teamviewer software, which is available on PC, Mac, Linux, Android and iPhone).

Since it is a "Meeting" the default is to share your screen for all clients to see. You can turn this off if you don't want your client to see your screen.

Then turn on "My Video" and all connected clients will be able to see the video, and also turn on "Voice over IP" which will allow your clients to hear you. They should also be able to talk back to you, and turn on video at their end as well (if they have the software - If they use the browser version, I think they can only be a passive participant - not 100% sure as I haven't tested this).

The meeting can be passworded, or if the streaming is only temporary, you can simply re-create the meeting which will generate a new meeting ID, and let your client know the new ID to connect to. If you want to hold the streaming/meeting for long time, setting password is probably a good idea.

And yes it is free for personal use.